# Non-vanishing vacuum expectation value and Non-unique vacuum state in symmetry breaking

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, symmetry, symmetry-breaking

I am trying to show that "Non-vanishing vacuum expectation value of some field" and "Non-unique vacuum state" are two equivalent definitions for symmetry breaking in a simple case. Below is what I am doing:

Now suppose we have a Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}(\phi^{i},\partial_{\mu}\phi^{i})$, $i=1,2,...N$, which is invariant under $SO(N)$, i.e., for $\phi^{'i}=\Lambda^{i}_{j}\phi^j$, $\Lambda \in SO(N)$, we have $\mathcal{L}(\phi^{i},\partial_{\mu}\phi^{i})=\mathcal{L}(\phi^{'i},\partial_{\mu}\phi^{'i})$.

Promoting field to operators, and let $|\Omega\rangle$ be a ground state(vacuum) such that $\langle\Omega|\hat{\phi^k}|\Omega\rangle$ is nonzero for some $k$. Then how shall we deal with $SO(N)$ ation on field operators and vacuum? Is it a unitary representation $U(\Lambda)$ and $U^{\dagger}(\Lambda)\hat{\phi^i}U(\Lambda)$ ? I guess another vacuum is $U(\Lambda)|\Omega\rangle$.

For other derection, suppose we have at least two distinct vacuums $|\Omega_1\rangle$ and $|\Omega_2\rangle$, then how to show that there is a field operator with non-vanishing expectation value?